# Alternative to deprecated Java Logger.logrb method

Tags: java

I have inherited Java code that is using the deprecated Logger.logrb method.  Is there a recommended alternative using this deprecated method?

Comment: *Ideally*, use slf4j.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html. It is mentioned what need to be used in case of deprecated method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/jdk8u12-docs/api/java/lang/class-use/Deprecated.html

A search for "logrb" finds the following:

> Logger.logrb(Level level, String sourceClass, String sourceMethod, String bundleName, String msg)
>   Deprecated. 
>   Use Logger.logrb(java.util.logging.Level, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.ResourceBundle, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...) instead.
>
> Logger.logrb(Level level, String sourceClass, String sourceMethod, String bundleName, String msg, Object param1)
>   Deprecated. 
>   Use Logger.logrb(java.util.logging.Level, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.ResourceBundle, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...) instead
>
> Logger.logrb(Level level, String sourceClass, String sourceMethod, String bundleName, String msg, Throwable thrown)
>   Deprecated. 
>   Use Logger.logrb(java.util.logging.Level, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.ResourceBundle, java.lang.String, java.lang.Throwable) instead.

Use one of the posted alternative methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the overloaded version of the logrb method:

[public void logrb(Level level,
                  String sourceClass,
                  String sourceMethod,
                  ResourceBundle bundle,
                  String msg,
                  Object... params)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#logrb-java.util.logging.Level-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.util.ResourceBundle-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)

The `ResourceBundle bundle` can be passed as null if you don't need it.